# Using a slider to variate the size of an array and display as a dynamic svg histogram?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

So I am trying to create a sorting visualizer similar to the one seen here by Clement Mihailescu: https://clementmihailescu.github.io/Sorting-Visualizer/

I am not using react but rather pure javascript, css, html, and the d3.js library.

My problem is that I have two functions. The first one detects whenever the user presses the "generate array" button, which is supposed to randomly assign values to the objects in the DUMMY_DATA array and display the correctly sized svg rectangles on the chart.

My other function is an update function which is tied to an event listener that detects whenever the user moves a slider and is supposed to dynamically change the size of the array (and therefore change the number of bars/rects being rendered on the screen). My main issue is that my code works fine when I move the slider below its max of 100, and it will remove bars from the screen accordingly all the way down to 1. When I move the slider back up, however, the bars are not re-rendered. I have added for loops to console.log the output of the values of the array and I can see that they are still there and are being changed, but I cannot figure out how to get the bars of the svg to render. The "generate array" button works fine when the size is changed as well but it also is changing the entire array and not just the range being defined by the slider. The code is posted below:

```js
const DUMMY_DATA = [{
    id: 'd1',
    value: 10
  },
  {
    id: 'd2',
    value: 11
  },
  {
    id: 'd3',
    value: 12
  },
  {
    id: 'd4',
    value: 6
  },
  {
    id: 'd5',
    value: 7
  },
  {
    id: 'd6',
    value: 13
  },
  {
    id: 'd7',
    value: 4
  },
  {
    id: 'd8',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    id: 'd9',
    value: 14
  },
  {
    id: 'd10',
    value: 3
  },
  {
    id: 'd11',
    value: 7
  },
  {
    id: 'd12',
    value: 6
  },
  {
    id: 'd13',
    value: 7
  },
  {
    id: 'd14',
    value: 9
  },
  {
    id: 'd15',
    value: 9
  },
  {
    id: 'd16',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    id: 'd17',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    id: 'd18',
    value: 15
  },
  {
    id: 'd19',
    value: 12
  },
  {
    id: 'd20',
    value: 7
  },
  {
    id: 'd21',
    value: 7
  },
  {
    id: 'd22',
    value: 8
  },
  {
    id: 'd23',
    value: 5
  },
  {
    id: 'd24',
    value: 5
  },
  {
    id: 'd25',
    value: 11
  },
  {
    id: 'd26',
    value: 11
  },
  {
    id: 'd27',
    value: 12
  },
  {
    id: 'd28',
    value: 10
  },
  {
    id: 'd29',
    value: 6
  },
  {
    id: 'd30',
    value: 13
  },
  {
    id: 'd31',
    value: 14
  },
  {
    id: 'd32',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    id: 'd33',
    value: 12
  },
  {
    id: 'd34',
    value: 11
  },
  {
    id: 'd35',
    value: 10
  },
  {
    id: 'd36',
    value: 5
  },
  {
    id: 'd37',
    value: 6
  },
  {
    id: 'd38',
    value: 7
  },
  {
    id: 'd39',
    value: 14
  },
  {
    id: 'd40',
    value: 14
  },
  {
    id: 'd41',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    id: 'd42',
    value: 0
  },
  {
    id: 'd43',
    value: 11
  },
  {
    id: 'd44',
    value: 15
  },
  {
    id: 'd45',
    value: 7
  },
  {
    id: 'd46',
    value: 13
  },
  {
    id: 'd47',
    value: 4
  },
  {
    id: 'd48',
    value: 4
  },
  {
    id: 'd49',
    value: 4
  },
  {
    id: 'd50',
    value: 11
  },
  {
    id: 'd51',
    value: 10
  },
  {
    id: 'd52',
    value: 5
  },
  {
    id: 'd53',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    id: 'd54',
    value: 6
  },
  {
    id: 'd55',
    value: 7
  },
  {
    id: 'd56',
    value: 0
  },
  {
    id: 'd57',
    value: 0
  },
  {
    id: 'd58',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    id: 'd59',
    value: 10
  },
  {
    id: 'd60',
    value: 11
  },
  {
    id: 'd61',
    value: 3
  },
  {
    id: 'd62',
    value: 13
  },
  {
    id: 'd63',
    value: 7
  },
  {
    id: 'd64',
    value: 13
  },
  {
    id: 'd65',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    id: 'd66',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    id: 'd67',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    id: 'd68',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    id: 'd69',
    value: 3
  },
  {
    id: 'd70',
    value: 7
  },
  {
    id: 'd71',
    value: 6
  },
  {
    id: 'd72',
    value: 10
  },
  {
    id: 'd73',
    value: 12
  },
  {
    id: 'd74',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    id: 'd75',
    value: 10
  },
  {
    id: 'd76',
    value: 11
  },
  {
    id: 'd77',
    value: 12
  },
  {
    id: 'd78',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    id: 'd79',
    value: 3
  },
  {
    id: 'd80',
    value: 13
  },
  {
    id: 'd81',
    value: 14
  },
  {
    id: 'd82',
    value: 12
  },
  {
    id: 'd83',
    value: 0
  },
  {
    id: 'd84',
    value: 11
  },
  {
    id: 'd85',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    id: 'd86',
    value: 5
  },
  {
    id: 'd87',
    value: 7
  },
  {
    id: 'd88',
    value: 3
  },
  {
    id: 'd89',
    value: 14
  },
  {
    id: 'd90',
    value: 12
  },
  {
    id: 'd91',
    value: 10
  },
  {
    id: 'd92',
    value: 10
  },
  {
    id: 'd93',
    value: 10
  },
  {
    id: 'd94',
    value: 6
  },
  {
    id: 'd95',
    value: 7
  },
  {
    id: 'd96',
    value: 13
  },
  {
    id: 'd97',
    value: 0
  },
  {
    id: 'd98',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    id: 'd99',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    id: 'd100',
    value: 11
  },
];

const xScale = d3
  .scaleBand() //Gives all bars/items the same width
  .domain(DUMMY_DATA.map((dataPoint) => dataPoint.id)) //Tells scaleBand() how many data points there are based on the number of ids
  .rangeRound([0, 1000]) //Sets the range of the area the bars are generated in, i.e. the width of the container
  .padding(0.1); //Puts padding between the bars
const yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear() //Gives y coordinates function to position the heights of the bars
  .domain([0, 15]) //Specifies the min and max range of height values of the bars
  .range([600, 0]); //Sets range of the height of the container that the bars will sit in

const container = d3.select('svg')
  .classed('container', true);

const bars = container
  .selectAll('.bar')
  .data(DUMMY_DATA)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .classed('bar', true)
  .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth()) //Takes available width and divides by the number of data points (ids) to give equal widths
  .attr('height', (data) => 600 - yScale(data.value))
  .attr('x', data => xScale(data.id))
  .attr('y', data => yScale(data.value));


/////////////////////////////////////////////   Generate button functions    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Grabs the "Generate Array" button
var newarr = document.getElementById("generate-array");
newarr.onclick = function() {
  //Find index of specific object using findIndex method. 
  objIndex = DUMMY_DATA.findIndex((obj => obj.id));

  //Log object to Console.
  for (objIndex in DUMMY_DATA) {
    console.log("Before update: ", DUMMY_DATA[objIndex])
  }

  //Update object's value properties.
  DUMMY_DATA.forEach(obj => {
    for (var i = 0; i < DUMMY_DATA.length; i++) {
      DUMMY_DATA[i].value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
    }
  });

  //Updates the bars with newly generated values
  container
    .selectAll('.bar')
    .data(DUMMY_DATA)
    .transition()
    .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr('height', (data) => 600 - yScale(data.value))
    .attr('x', data => xScale(data.id))
    .attr('y', data => yScale(data.value));

  //Log object to console again.
  for (objIndex in DUMMY_DATA) {
    console.log("After update: ", DUMMY_DATA[objIndex])
  }

  container.exit()
    .remove()
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////   Slider functions    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");

// Display the default slider value and print to console
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
console.log(slider.value)

update = () => {

  //Output currently updated slider value and print to console
  output.innerHTML = slider.value;
  console.log(slider.value)

  //Take portion of original dataset
  SLIDER_DATA = DUMMY_DATA.splice(0, slider.value)

  // Create the u variable
  var u = container.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(SLIDER_DATA)

  //Update object's value properties.
  SLIDER_DATA.forEach(obj => {
    for (var i = 0; i < SLIDER_DATA.length; i++) {
      // console.log(`${key}: ${obj[key]}`);
      SLIDER_DATA[i].value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);

    }
  });

  //Updates the bars with newly generated values
  u
    .transition()
    .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr('height', (data) => 600 - yScale(data.value))
    .attr('x', data => xScale(data.id))
    .attr('y', data => yScale(data.value))

  // If less group in the new dataset, I delete the ones not in use anymore
  u
    .exit()
    .transition() // and apply changes to all of them
    .duration(1000)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .remove()

  DUMMY_DATA.splice(0, 0, ...SLIDER_DATA);

}
//Event listener to detect when slider is being used and invoke update
slider.addEventListener('input', update);
```

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #720570;
}

.bar {
  fill: #720570;
}
```

```html
<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v3.min.js"></script>

<div id="toolbar">
  <button type="button" class="algorithmButton" id="generate-array">Generate Array</button>
  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
    <p style="padding-left: 8px">Value:<span id="demo" style="padding-left: 5px"></span></p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<svg></svg>
```

I am new to both javascript and d3.js and this is the first program I have really tried to write with either, but I have used python and c++ before. I am not sure if the problem is with my javascript or my svg manipulation with d3.js or what. Any help is greatly appreciated as I have been trying to figure this out for about a week now!

Comment: Manipulating an array or objects of an array in place is generally considered to be a source of bugs and should be avoided. It's somewhat abstract and out of scope, but have a look at deep vs shallow copying for example.

Comment: As has been pointed out, you could probably achieve your desired results more easily by not changing the array in place. Bars aren't being added because you have no `.enter().append('rect')` on the change events.

Comment: Thank you both so much I got it to work! @SmokeyShakers I am still getting used to d3.js so I forgot to actually append the rects again, and I'm using slice instead of splice now so that the original Array isn't modified!

Comment: Thats great. In my experience, the more you can wrap your head around the whole enter, exit, join, etc, the easier D3 is to use.